# How can I send an image file from firebase functions?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

There are a lot of descriptions about uploading and resizing an image to a firebase function. But I want to do the opposite.

I want to deliver an image through a firebase function as an answer to a request.
And I want to use cors!

I really struck here, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a full firebase function code using TypeScript and Puppeteer to take a screenshot and set response to the screenshot.

```js
    import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
    import * as puppeteer from "puppeteer";
    
    const runtimeOpts = {
      timeoutSeconds: 120,
      memory: <const> '1GB'
    };
    
    export const search = functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
      try {
        const imageBuffer: Buffer = await generateScreenShot();
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png'});
        response.write(imageBuffer.toString('binary'), 'binary');
        response.end()
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    })
    
    function generateScreenShot(): Promise<Buffer> {
      return new Promise<Buffer>(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']});
          const page = await browser.newPage();
          await page.goto('http://example.ee', {
            waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
          });
          await page.waitFor(500);
          const imageBuffer: Buffer = await page.screenshot({fullPage: true});
          await browser.close();
    
          resolve(imageBuffer);
        } catch (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Functions is essentially a wrapper around Node.js modules. HTTP triggered Cloud Functions are essentially a wrapper around Express. Knowing this, you can search for [node.js send image response](https://www.google.com/search?q=node.js+send+image+response) or [node.js express send image response](https://www.google.com/search?q=node.js+express+send+image+response) to get a lot of good results.

In one of my projects, I did something like this:

```
var stream = webshot(tweet_url, { 
  captureSelector: `.tweet[data-tweet-id='${getTweetId(tweet_url)}']`,
  customCSS: "div.follow-bar { display: none }",
});
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'});
stream.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(`Sending ${data.length} bytes`);
  res.write(data.toString('binary'), 'binary');
});
stream.on('end', function() {
  console.log('Done');
  res.end();
})
```

Where `webshot` is a function that creates a screenshot and returns a stream to the binary data for that.